# How can I reference the String path in the String lines?

Tags: java, string, methods

I have a String which is located in a separate class that I would like to reference in another String.

```
public static void filedemo(String[] args) {
    FileDemo.readLibDir("C:/test/lib");
}

public static void readLibDir(String directoryname) {
    File dir = null;
    String[] paths;
    try {
        dir = new File(directoryname);
        paths = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File directory, String name) {
                // return only files that end .jar extension
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar");
            }
        });
        // enhanced for loop used to iterate through the array
        for (String path : paths) {
            // check to see if jar filename exist  
            boolean found = FileNameStorage.exists(path);
            if (found) {
                // didn't find
                FileNameStorage.delete(path);
            } else {
                System.out.print(path+" was not found.\n ");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if any error occurs
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class HtmlDataTable {
    String lines = "<tr>  <td>" + jarfilename + "</td>  <td>"
                        + paths + " </td> <td>" + jarfilename
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in its current form this looks a lot more like a statement than a question.

Comment: Why did you revert back the edit??

Comment: I am not sure what String in what Class needs to be accessible?

Comment: @MaxZoom The String paths, the original question was edited and I'm trying to understand why so if I made a mistake I can correct it in the future.

Comment: Can you include the whole `FileDemo` class code with it?

Comment: @MaxZoom all of the code form the FileDemo class is included.If there is any thing missing it was edited out by a moderator. I'm trying to reference the String paths in the String lines which is located in a different class.

Comment: Both methods listed are `static`, which means their variables are local and can not be accessed outside method.

Comment: You need to do two things: 1) Write your problem statement. Basically, WHAT problem are you trying to solve, and 2) HOW you attempted to solve it.  IMO, the problem you are trying to solve is not described clearly at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your `paths` variable is local to a method. Hence it cannot be accessed from any other class (or even from any other method in the same class). Have a look at [Variable Scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html), or google about it.

If you want to access `paths` from other class, your easiest option would be to make it an instance variable and make it public.

Comment: How do I make an instance variable of paths?

Comment: Just declare it outside all the methods in the class... Just like how you have declared your `lines` string.

Comment: I didn't write the code so I'm not sure how to declare it outside all the methods in the class.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, the variable `paths` should be defined as class member  (currently is defined as local variable in a static method).
 Only then you can make it available to the outside caller.

One way to do it is as below:

```
public class FileDemo {
  private final File dir;

  // constructor
  public FileDemo (String directoryname) {
    dir = new File(directoryname);
  }

  public String[] getPaths() {
    return dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
       public boolean accept(File directory, String name) {
         // return only files that end .jar extension
         return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar");
       }
    });
  }
  :

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileDemo demo = new FileDemo("C:/test/lib");
    String[] paths = demo.getPaths();
    :  // now it is available 
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about the structure of your code. Are all of these methods loacted in the FileDemo class? Actually I see you added a main method also disregard the question.

Comment: Only first two methods are relevant. The third static method is only a driver to show how to use these methods. It could be removed and similar code created in the caller.